# Obtener la duracion de un video en django

Tags: python, django, archivo

Quisiera saber cómo obtener la duración de un vídeo en Django.
He intentado usando [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-the-duration-of-a-video-in-python/36743499#36743499), pero no se puede porque ese código reciben el nombre del archivo como `string` y si el archivo se encuentra en otro directorio también se le debe pasar todo junto: `../ejemplo/hola.mp4`

Según parece, los archivos antes de ser guardados se guardan de forma temporal. Tengo la ruta y el nombre de al archivo pero nada sucede, ya no se que intentar:

```
  def clean_archivo_video(self):
    file_f = self.cleaned_data['archivo_video']
    mime = magic.from_buffer(file_f.read(), mime=True)
    if mime != 'video/mp4':
    raise forms.ValidationError('Sube un archivo de MP4.')

    ff = UploadedFile(file_f)
    yy = ff._get_name()
    fff = TemporaryUploadedFile(ff._get_name(), ff.content_type, ff.size, ff.charset)
    uu = fff.temporary_file_path()
    www = str(uu+'/'+yy)
    print www
    video_file_path = www
    print duration(video_file_path)
    return file_f
```

Con el código de arriba obtengo el nombre del archivo(no el que voy a guardar en la base de datos sino con el que se guarda en el directorio temporal) y el lugar donde se encuentra el archivo pero nada sucede.

Intente las otras soluciones de las otras respuestas pero ninguna funciona en Django. Fuera de Django le paso el nombre del archivo como `string` como parámetro y funciona bien el problema es que no funciona dentro de Django.

Comment: y porque mejor no usas FFmpeg para Obtener la duracion de un video y su datos asi en mas facil

Answer (score 3):

Creo que no hay módulos de Python para eso. La traducción de la pregunta relacionada en SO<sup>1</sup> dice:

Tal vez tengas que usar un programa externo. [`fprobe`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) puede darte la información que necesitas.

```
import subprocess

def getLength(filename):
    result = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ffprobe", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
    return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]
```

<sup>1</sup> Los créditos son para el usuario [@SingleNegationElimination](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65696/singlenegationelimination), Enlace a la pregunta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844467/783618)